# Align Monthly Results for the Same Control into One Row

Tags: session, row, resultset, distributed, webi

I have 12 session results over the course of a year.

The results all relate to one control but the control is performed monthly.  At the month the table displays as follows:

[Control Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5eDg.png)

I would like the results to show in one row and across monthly columns rather than as above where the results are shown across monthly columns but a new row is taken with each result.

I've tried to use merge/breaks and grouping of the control but this has not worked. I am using the following formula to locate the session result for each month:

```
January (for example):`    =If([Calendar Month]="January") Then [Query 1].[IC CM SESSION Result]
Calendar Month :     =Month([IC CM SESSION Start Date])
```

In the table reference the fields are as follows from left to right:
Control Name     =[IC CM SESSION Subject]
Frequency     =[Query 1].[IC CM Monitor Frequency]
January     =If([Calendar Month]="January") Then [Query 1].[IC CM SESSION Result]

Answer (score 0):

Either I am misunderstanding your requirement or you are overthinking this. All you need is a crosstab with month of your start date as the column header.

I created a report with the following free-hand SQL query...

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE, '2023-01-15') AS [Start Date], 'Effective' AS [Session Result]
UNION SELECT '2023-01-15', 'Effective'
UNION SELECT '2023-02-15', 'Effective'
UNION SELECT '2023-03-15', 'Effective'
UNION SELECT '2023-04-15', 'Effective'
UNION SELECT '2023-05-15', 'Effective'
UNION SELECT '2023-06-15', 'Effective'
UNION SELECT '2023-07-15', 'Effective'
UNION SELECT '2023-08-15', 'Overdue'
UNION SELECT '2023-09-15', 'Effective'
```

That gives me the following table...

[image]

I created a **Month Start Date** variable much like your **Calendar Month** variable...

```
=Month([Start Date])
```

I made that the column header in my crosstab. When using a crosstab you usually have have a measure to put in the body. In your case you want Session Result. If you put Session Result in the body as a dimension you will not get your desired result. However, we can create a **Max Session Result** variable which result result in a measure as follows...

```
=Max([Session Result])
```

Put that object in the body of the crosstab and there you have it.

[image]

You will need to apply a custom sort order to **Month Start Date** to get it to display in calendar order. You will also need to add your own row header to the crosstab where I have "Session Result" if you want something there.

Noel